# How can I sort a string case insensitively without using java.util.Arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

`input: bbDeaAcCc`

`output: AabbCccDe`

I'm trying to sort a string case-insensitively without importing anything. It's easy to do this with `java.util.Arrays`, but I can't figure out a way to do it without it. I've only gotten as far as sorting it to ACDabbcce...got any ideas?

```java
String str = "bbDeaAcCc";
char[] strArr = str.toCharArray();
char temp = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++) {
        if (strArr[j] > strArr[i]) { 
            temp = strArr[i];
            strArr[i] = strArr[j];
            strArr[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You’d just have to write your own sort; about which there are so many questions on this site, as well as both academic and didactic books and articles that  covering it again would not be helpful.

Comment: Also your order doesn’t look case insensitive - it looks like you want to sort alphabetically then capital letters first; the order of `aA` is swapped in your sorted example.

Comment: count the characters in a `int[]` and print them in order of A-Z in parallel with a-z.

Comment: What you need to do to finish your sort implementation is to **compare** the pair of characters at `i` and `j` to decide if they should be swapped.  The test needs to implement your sorting criteria ... which are not clear from your question.   (This is simple coding, and you should attempt it yourself before asking more questions about it.)

Answer (score 2):

As one of the solutions, you can use `PriorityQueue`.

```java
public static String sortIgnoreCase(String str) {
    Queue<Character> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(
          Comparator.comparingInt((ToIntFunction<Character>)Character::toLowerCase)
                    .thenComparingInt(ch -> (int)ch));

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
        queue.add(str.charAt(i));

    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(str.length());

    while (!queue.isEmpty())
        buf.append(queue.remove());

    return buf.toString();
}
```

---

In case you have only the **letters**, you can do it without special structure:

```java
public static String sortIgnoreCase(String str) {
    int[] lowerCase = new int[26];
    int[] upperCase = new int[lowerCase.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char ch = str.charAt(i);

        if (Character.isLowerCase(ch))
            lowerCase[ch - 'a']++;
        else if (Character.isUpperCase(ch))
            upperCase[ch - 'A']++;
    }

    char[] res = new char[str.length()];

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < lowerCase.length; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < upperCase[i]; k++)
            res[j++] = (char)(i + 'A');
        for (int k = 0; k < lowerCase[i]; k++)
            res[j++] = (char)(i + 'a');
    }

    return new String(res);
}
```

---

And finally, using your approach, you can use `InsertionSort`:

```java
public static String sortIgnoreCase(String str) {
    char[] arr = str.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = i; j >= 1; j--) {
            int res = Integer.compare(Character.toLowerCase(arr[j - 1]),
                                      Character.toLowerCase(arr[j]));

            if (res == 0 && arr[j - 1] < arr[j] || res < 0)
                break;

            swap(arr, j - 1, j);
        }
    }

    return new String(arr);
}

private static void swap(char[] arr, int i, int j) {
    char tmp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = tmp;
}
```

Comment: “_without importing anything_”. However ridiculous the constraint, it’s still the constraint in the question.

Comment: In the title, it says *"without using java.util.Arrays"*

Comment: You’ll have to ask the OP, but I would suppose that is the way they know using imports. Either way, it does say no imports.

Comment: @BoristheSpider anyway, thank you for point that. I have added another example.